# Picasa on WINE didnt create an icon (12.10), how to start it?

Tags: wine, google-picasa

I have just installed Picasa using

```
sudo apt-get install wine winetricks 
cd ~/ && wget http://dl.google.com/picasa/picasa39-setup.exe 
wine ~/picasa39-setup.exe
```

It is installed, because I can start it from the shell. How can I add an icon to the dash to easily start Picasa in Ubuntu 12.10 (as I had in 12.04)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently after I restarted the computer Ubuntu Dash identified Picasa and I am now able to add it to the sidebar.